# Delete an S3 directory via Ansible playbooks

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

Is there a way to delete S3 directories recursively with all their content using Ansible playbooks or am I forced to use shell scripts?

Currently `aws_s3` and `s3_object` modules only offer deleting empty directories using `delobj` mode. I'm looking for a bulk deletion based on directory/key prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll actually observe by running `aws --debug` that even with aws-cli the `rm --recursive` behavior is to first enumerate the keys and then delete them one at a time. Thus, if you wanted to do it via ansible, you would need to replicate that behavior using `mode: list` plus `register:` and taking care if you have more than the 1000 default returned keys, likely via [the `marker:` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/amazon/aws/s3_object_module.html#parameter-marker)

The only alternative that I've ever heard is to use the S3 lifecycle policy to remove objects, if you have an incredible amount of them